# IIS doesn't run on HTTPS protocol in localhost

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, https, ssl-certificate, visual-studio-2019

when i run my `Asp.net core 3.1` app with `IIS`, i encounter with:

[image]

but when i run it on `HTTP` protocol, it runs well.
I reinstall my Chrome,VS and IIS and also reinstall my `SSL certificate` with the help : [Troubleshoot certificate problems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#trust)
but the problem remains!

> `Additional information:`
>
> `IIS`:10 | `VS`:2019 | `Windows`:10 version-1909 | `Chrome`:version-84
>
> also i used to work without problem in my other windows user
> account,but i had to delete that and work with new user account.

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html Run a report and the issues should be clear.

Comment: Could you find tha request in either IIS log or httperr(C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR) log？ And how did you set the binding host header? Besides, did you face this issue if you replace the cert with a self-signed trusted certificate? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/benjaminperkins/make-your-own-ssl-certificate-for-testing-and-learning

Comment: i found it out that my antivirus ("Kaspersky") blocks  my localhost SSL certificate!

Comment: @nimaansari, and how did you manage to add it to exclusions? I am experiecing exactly the same problem after the last update of the AV.

Comment: @IvayloDimitrov  i tried a lot, but the problem remained. so i uninstalled my antivirus.

Comment: @nimaansari, i'll try to contact Kaspersky and write here if they resolve the issue

Comment: @IvayloDimitrov if it is possible for you, first install Kaspersky, then install VS and other related stuff(in new windows!). it solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with Kaspersky and Visual Studio on Windows 10, and finally resolved it by disabling the Encrypted Connection Scanning in Settings > Network Settings, then restarting my machine.

[image: Network Settings]

It might be possible to add localhost to exclusions, but this didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: I have a same situation, but this doesn't help. I have to disable my Kaspersky completely! After a few minutes, it works! I don't understand which antivirus/firewall module is responsible

Comment: I just upgraded my Kaspersky to the new version 21.2.16.590 and the situation was gone